# Issue with implementing two way data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, httpclient

I am implementing a CRUD operation,where two way data binding isn't working.

**update-product.htm:**

```
<form #productForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateProduct(productForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment">Product description:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="description" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.description"></textarea>
        </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="qua">Quality</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="qua" name="quality" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.quality">
          <option>Grade-1</option>
          <option>Grade-2</option>
          <option>Grade-3</option>
        </select>
      </div>     
      <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

I'm facing error here at both product.description and product.quality.

**update-prod.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.routes.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.id = +params['id'];
       });
       this.productService.getProducts()
       .subscribe((data: Response) => {
         this.products = JSON.stringify(data);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
         if ((this.procuts[i].id) === (this.id)) {
           this.product= this.products[i];

         }
       }
       });
  }

 updateProduct(form: any) {
  this.productService.updateProducts(form, this.id).subscribe(
    (data: any) => data.json()
  );
      this.route.navigate(['/update']);
 }
```

**update-service:**

```
updateProducts(productForm, id) {
        const temp = {
            'description': productForm.description,
            'quality': productForm.quality
        };
        return this.httpObj.put(`${this.uri}/products/${id}`, JSON.stringify(temp), {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
    });
  }
```

One more big issue is that after any CRUD operation ,the page doesn't get auto-updated even after adding router.

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Tasty apples",
      "quality": "Grade-1",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Juicy mangoes",
      "quality": "Grade-2",

    }}
```

And product is an object adds the values in it through looping.

Comment: You have to include the error message you get. What do you have as error in console devtool as well.

Comment: No error message. I just don't see the data added in update product form

Comment: [Angular] Identifier 'quality' is not defined. 'Object' does not contain such a member    ---> This is the error message displayed in vscode

Comment: You have to verify your ``product`` class or try ``[(ngModel)]="product?.quality"``

Comment: verified product..adding '?' doesn't help

Comment: @SiddAjmera Can u help out?

Comment: Can you create a stackbliz?

Comment: In the `for` loop, you have `this.procuts[i]` instead of `this.products[i]`. By the way, you could replace the loop with `this.product = this.products.find(x => x.id === this.id);`. It would simplify the code. According to the error message that you get, it looks like `this.product` does not have the `quality` property.

Comment: I corrected the typo and added above code, that didnt fix

Comment: if you use the old and deprecated http you should not do it. if you use httpClient you sould not use JSON.stringify nor data.json

Comment: I dont think that json.stringify or data.json is causing the issue here

Comment: The problem is probably the declaration of `product` and `products`. Can you include them in the question?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have updated

Comment: try  this.products = JSON.stringify(data).products;

Comment: The intellisense doesn't show up .products in  JSON.stringify(data).products